# Чем SDK Pack отличается от Targeting Pack?

Tags: .net

При установке можно выбрать отдельно SDK и отдельно Targeting Pack'и.

Но какое между ними конкретное различие?

Targeting Pack более "обезжиренный" и содержит меньше данных, а SDK включает в себя документацию?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Framework SDK от Microsoft нужен для разработки приложений для .NET Framework. Включает в себя:

- Документацию
- Заголовочные файлы (header files)
- Библиотеки
- Примеры и инстументы (Samples and tools).

Вместе с установкой visual studio этого достаточно.

**НО!**

Если вы пишете под более раннюю версию клиента .NET framework (а не текущую) , то в дополнение к SDK потребуется Targeting pack.

---

Оригинал с en.SO: [What's the difference between the .NET Framework SDK and the Targeting pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147609/whats-the-difference-between-the-net-framework-sdk-and-the-targeting-pack)